# jquery selector on multiple id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi have a html code like this

```
<input type="text" value="quantita" id="quantita" name="quantita">
<input type="text" value="prodotto" id="prodotto" name="prodotto">
<input type="text" value="prezzo" id="prezzo" name="prezzo">
```

Now I'm trying to do a jquery code that add a button if the value of all these id is different from NULL

so I do this

```
var list = $("#prezzo", "#quantita", "#prodotto").val();
if (list!="")
{...do this...}
else
{....do nothing...}
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: You need to check each element individually, not all at once with `if (list!="")`

Comment: Syntax error at `$("#prezzo", "#quantita", "#prodotto")` ? Multiple selectors should be within same string , unbroken by actual comma operator `,` , inside double quotes as single selector ; e.g., `$("#prezzo, #quantita, #prodotto")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#prezzo,#quantita,#prodotto").each(function()
{
   if ($(this).val() !="" )
   {}
   else
   {}
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this instead

```
var list = $("#prezzo, #quantita, #prodotto").filter(function() {
    return this.value === "";
}).length === 0;

if (list) { // All values set
```

assuming you meant the value is an empty string, as in no value set, and not actually the string `NULL` ?